# Why can't I use `BIGNUM` in this C struct declaration?

Tags: c, openssl, libssl

I was experimenting with some ~2005 C code (using OpenSSL 0.9.8, I think) and I tried `make`-ing it with OpenSSL 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Minimum example:

```c
#include <openssl/bn.h>

struct fraction
{
    BIGNUM numerator;
    BIGNUM denominator;
}
```

Expected: everything builds, just as intended.

Actual: complier complains about incomplete type declaration for both fields.

Why does this happen? Is this not a valid declaration? Or is it something else?

Comment: `BIGNUM` is probably an [opaque type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type), which in C is usually implemented using something like `struct bignum` without ever actually defining what's in `struct bignum` in a way accessible to callers.  In this case `BIGNUM` is probably a `typedef` to a similar `struct` that's not visible. (I don't have the time right now to actually look into the OpenSSL 3 definition of `BIGNUM` to see if that's the actual answer, hence this comment)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I'll try modifying it to use pointers.

Comment: In the future please provide full unedited error messages as you see them, or the first few lines if there are too many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later versions of OpenSSL made several types opaque, including `BIGNUM`, which means you can't instantiate them directly in user code.  The `BIGNUM` type in particular became an opaque type starting with version 1.1.0.

You would instead need to use pointers:

```
struct fraction
{
    BIGNUM *numerator;
    BIGNUM *denominator;
};
```

And use the appropriate functions to create and destroy them, as well as use the relevant accessor functions to access the members.